# Count number of chords with points on circumference of a circle

Tags: combinatorics

There are $p\ge6$ points given on circumference of a circle, and every two points are joined by a chord. **Assume that no 3 chords are concurrent within the interior of the circle**.
We have to find the number of intersection points made by these chords inside the circle.

---

We count the ways to choose 4 points out of $p$ and each set of the chosen points contributes to a single intersection point inside the circle. So the answer is $$p\choose4$$
But I cannot understand the significance of the condition in bold. How will the answer change without this condition?

Comment: That assumption is there, because otherwise the answer would not be unique. If you have got the answer to this question, you should write it down with the question, so that we can point out, at which step of the answer have you implicitly used the assumption.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I don't understand how the answer will not be unique

Comment: Think of $n=6$ and the configuration where the points are the vertices of a regular hexagon. That will have fewer intersection points than the generic case.

Comment: Each set of points contributes to a single intersection point inside the circle, correct. How do you  know that two *different* sets of points always contribute *different* end points? If this were not true, then you would overcount the intersection points. The hypothesis ensures that this is true.

Comment: Same formula works for $p=4,5.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have three concurrent lines (i.e. all intersecting at a single point). Now perturb the position of the line endpoints slightly. Almost surely the lines no longer intersect a single point; instead you have three pairwise intersections and a tiny triangle where the single intersection point used to be. Therefore any time you have (exactly) three concurrent lines, you "lose" two intersection points from the number predicted by your formula.